# how to push notifications into android app using java RESTful web services

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I'm writing an android app which must receive notifications from a java RESTful webservice ,like in gcm (google cloud messaging). If anyone knows how this is done, please point me to a tutorial. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An android app can't receive HTTP messages like a server can. You can either use GCM or implement some kind of polling system that retrieves the information for you.

Weak solution:
Using an alarm manager you could poll the server every 10 seconds for example and get any information that was stored for you.

Better solution:
Use long polling, by this I mean with your app you should send across a HTTP message and have it sit and wait for like 30 seconds, if no new data is sent to the server then it will just return with no data and go straight back again. If at any point during that 30 second period the server receives some data, then add it to a list and tell the message to release back to the phone with the list. That will only really work if you are expecting the same type of information everytime.

Best solution:
Again, use long polling. However, instead of releasing the HTTP message back to the phone with the new data, return a list of the new types of data received, like you could tell it there is a new text message waiting. The phone will then be aware of a pending message when it gets the response back, you can then just send a Get message and retrieve the message from a stored list.

Hope that helps, explained it kind of quick!

For help on building a Java RESTful service, look at this link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I'm going off the assumption you already understand how the RESTful service works, and if not then that link should help. As far as an example for the 'Better solution', just start by making a basic service with a GET call that returns a string so you know it's working. When you have that going you just need a method to poll every x seconds that returns a list of the new data..

```
/**
 * This is the method you poll every x seconds
 * @return
 */
public List<Location> eventPoll() {
    ArrayList<Location> oldData = new ArrayList<>(m_Location);

    // small possibility this could get a new piece of data thats not in 'oldData' and
    // which would be cleared. Would be better looping through removing each piece
    // individually comparing it to the oldData
    m_Location.clear();

    return oldData;
}
```

I'm not sure how you plan on getting the location data into your service, but for the sake of simplicity just add it to an ArrayList like so..

```
/**
 * This is the method that stores the new data
 * @return
 */
public Location storeNewLocation(Location location) {
    m_Location.add(location);
}
```

** WARNING, not been tested. Literally just wrote it in here now **

Again, this is all going off the assumption you know how to do the previous parts (building up the service), if not then that code isn't much help yet. Good luck!

Comment: actually i've tried a lot using gcm , but some of google services are blocked in my country, and notifications don't reach to the android app..
the better solution looks fine by me .because the user in my app is moving and needs to update his information as you said (location ) and notifications depends on this location >>thanks and if you have an example about this idea please share it